# Replace image dynamically on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, launch-screen

I have an image in my project which is of a default human portrait, I show this in the LaunchScreen.xib on application launch.

When the user has signed up in the application I then want to over-write the default human portrait image, the idea being that the LaunchScreen.xib will now show the custom image that they have supplied.

Is this possible? And if so does anyone have any tips about how I might go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Launch screen is is not a fully customizable view controller. You cannot specify a custom class name in the storyboard and expect the system to give you the option to execute code at this stage. Remember, the app hasn’t launched yet so you cannot do that how you want. Instead, you may create some other lightweight controller that will appear as soon as app loaded and display for few seconds user image

Comment: Thing is - I don't want to specify a customisable view controller. What I want to do is to overwrite one of the images referenced in the XIB with my own custom image.

i.e. Physically overwrite the contents of "MyImage.png" with something else.